# Run expect in PHP

Tags: php, expect

I have an index.php as given below.

```
<?php
    $v = passthru("expect ./script2.exp qbadmin password hostname 'root_password' 6969") > &1;
    echo "==========" . $v;
?>
```

and my expect script is as follows,

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set username [lindex $argv 0]
set pass [lindex $argv 2]
set host [lindex $argv 1]
set rootpass [lindex $argv 3]
set port [lindex $argv 4]
spawn ssh -o GSSAPIAuthentication=no $username@$host -p $port
expect -timeout 3 "*(yes/no)?" { send "yes\r";exp_continue }
expect -timeout 3 "*d: "
send "$pass\n"
expect -timeout 3 "*$ "
send "su -\r"
expect -timeout 3 "*d: "
send "$rootpass\r"
expect -timeout 3 "*#"
send "ls /home\r"
interact
```

And when I load the index.php file in browser, it looks like the one given below.

[image]

My intention is to display the output of second last command in the expect script `ls /home` in browser. What modification shall I need to do here. When I run the expect script alone it gives the correct output.Please advice me as I am beginner in  php.

Comment: `<pre>` is your friend!!!

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Could you please elaborate or give some goog tutorials ?

Comment: I mean `echo "<pre>"; $v = passthru(...); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you execute a php-script on the console it got your permissions.

running a script in a browser means a webserver is executing it.

If you got a apache running the user should be www-data.

You should create the directory /var/www/.ssh and give the www-data user write permissions in this folder.